# cost function is continuosly increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression, data-science

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("FuelConsumption.csv")
df = df[['ENGINE SIZE','CYLINDERS', 'Mcity', 'Mhwy', 'Mcmb', 'McmbMPG', 'CO2']]

features = np.asanyarray(df[['ENGINE SIZE','CYLINDERS', 'Mcity', 'Mhwy', 'Mcmb', 'McmbMPG']])
label    = np.asanyarray(df[['CO2']])

mu = np.mean(features,axis=0)
sigma = np.std(features,axis=0)
feature_normalized = (features - mu)/sigma

n_training_samples = feature_normalized.shape[0]
n_dim = feature_normalized.shape[1]

feature_reshaped = np.reshape(features,[n_training_samples,n_dim])
label_reshaped = np.reshape(label,[n_training_samples,1])

train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split\
                 (feature_reshaped, label_reshaped,shuffle = True , test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
print("shape of training input = ", train_X.shape)
print("shape of training output = ", train_Y.shape)


numFeatures = train_X.shape[1]
print("Number of features = ", numFeatures)
numLabels = train_Y.shape[1]
print("Number of labels = ", numLabels)

learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,numFeatures])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,numLabels])
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([numFeatures,numLabels]))
B = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,numLabels]))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

Y_model = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W, name="apply_weights"), B, name="add_bias")
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y_model - Y))
training_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

loss_values = []
train_data = []
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
_, loss_val, a_val, b_val = sess.run([training_step, cost, W, B],feed_dict={X: train_X,Y: train_Y})
loss_values.append(loss_val)
if epoch % 20 == 0:
    print(epoch, loss_val, a_val, b_val)
    train_data.append([a_val, b_val])


plt.plot(loss_values, '--')
plt.show()
```

I am trying to predict CO2 emission using multiple variables like Cyliners, Milage, engine size etc using linear regression. I used above code in tensorflow. When I try to run the model loss value, weight and biases are getting updated only for 20 iterations and after that they are infinity(Nan). The problem here is with the code or selection of cost function/Optimizer?

I have plotted loss values which looks like [image: this].

If only Engine size and cylinders are used as features result is good. Any other features(Milage in city, Milage in highway, Milage combined) results in the above mentioned problem. I am attching the scttered plot of Mcity, Mhwy. Is it a problem with data itself?Please take a look at scattered plot of milage in city and hwy.[image]
[image]

Comment: You are initializing all your weights to 1. It could be that this creates the divergence you are seeing. Try to add some noise to the weight initialization.

Comment: I think the implementation is right , but the problem is comming from your initialization choice tf.ones , try with tf.zeros , or  choose random values uniformly between [-0,2,0.2]

Comment: I tried initializing weights and biases to randomely distributed values using tf.random_normal and also with all zeroes. The result is the same.